# Is there an open source radial diagram class for .net or php?

Tags: diagram, radial

I cannot find any libraries that will produce a radial diagram.  I said .net or php, but it could be jQuery and I pull back data from a web service for it.  I don't know how to implement it yet.  I am just looking for a radial diagram open source project.  I have searched and couldn't find anything.

I am aware of mind map but couldn't see how to use that in building an application.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/index.php) is an awesome php diagram/charp/pie, etc graphic class. (not quite sure about radial diagrams)

You could also use [php-gnuplot](http://php-gnuplot.sourceforge.net/), a very powerfull ploting sowftware.